# Issue using Mysqli in PHP class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm new to object-oriented PHP, and am having issues with the following code. Database queries with Mysqli aren't working within the class, but work fine outside. So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

```
class webFile {

    private $sql, $query;

    function __construct() {
        $sql = new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
    }

    function doQuery() {
        $queryText = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE number = '2'";
        if($query = $this->sql->query($queryText)) {
            $results = $query->fetch_array();
            return $results['post_id'];
        } else {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}

$object = new webFile();
echo $object->doQuery();
```

The server error log says "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object"... have I made another dumb mistake? I've looked around online, but can't find anything related to this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your constructor you set the mysqli to the local variable `$sql`

change your constructor to

```
 function __construct() {
        $this->sql = new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Miguelo said, the problem is that you wrote ***$sql instead of $this->sql*** in constructor.

But there is also the other problem.

As you can see, in your code you have got

```
private $sql, $query
```

I do not think that you want to use ***$query*** between functions in class, so I would remove it and leave:

```
private $sql;
```

But if you want to use it between functions that ***function doQuery()*** should look like this:

```
function doQuery() {
    $queryText = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE number = '2'";
    if($this->query = $this->sql->query($queryText)) {
        $results = $this->query->fetch_array();
        return $results['post_id'];
    } else {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP issue. As of this post PHP does not support nested classes. There's a chance that might change in version 7.0 but to my knowledge it isn't in the pipeline.

I think your best bet would be to simply use your class to extend the MySQLi class as in:

```
 class webFile extends mysqli {
```

You might want to lock it down some. Speaking of, note that MySQLi's construct won't be called automatically by your own __construct() method so you might have to work around that.

You can also use MySQLi's procedural functionality to achieve the desired result without having to extend MySQLi's class which is what I was looking into when I found this post which currently has over 2600 views and no definitively correct answer to your question.

PHP's object orientation isn't as robust as some, hopefully this will change in the years to come. PHP 7.0 supports anonymous class instantiation which is a sign that it might soon support nested classes.

EDIT: I found a link on PHP.net that covers overriding the construct. Apparently your own construct won't overwrite MySQLi's but you do have to call it manually as in:

```
 parent::__construct($host,$user,$pass,$db);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score -1):

For some reason it appears that your $SQL Variable isn't being set to an instance of the MySQLi Object.

I don't personally use MySQLi too frequently myself; as I'm preferential toward mysql_connect.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
$this->sql = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die( mysql_error());
$this->db = mysql_select_db($db) or die( mysql_error());
```

Or if you're set on the MySQLi Object -

```
try
{
    $this->sql = new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // throw another exception or something
}
```

Assuming that the connection throws an error - this will let you know that it has failed and allow you to make a correction.

Comment: all the mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Well sorry for not being up to date on the PHP documentation - I wasn't aware that this meant that it wasn't a valid solution. Thanks for the point down. <explitive>

Comment: the answer is valid, but you are sending him to a closed road

Comment: Assessed it as a bumpy road myself, not quite closed... But I gave him a detour too. Appreciate the reputation either way. Thanks bud.

Answer (score -1):

In php 5.3 doing initializing the mysqli object inside a class constructor breaks the code. I had to pass the mysqli object as a parameter to the class for it to work.
This is invalid :

```
function __construct() {
     $this->sql = new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
 }
```

But this will work :

```
function __construct($mysqli) {
     $this->sql = new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
 }
```

where $mysqli parameter can be

```
new mysqli('host','user','pass','dbname');
```

passed from the executing php script.
The mysqli class seems to have an issue I hope they will fix this in php 7.
The other work around would be to extend it as outline in the php manual pages.